# Perl GetOptions or die not working as intended

Tags: perl

I am writing a simple code which takes in an argument at command line and does some processing. I want the script to "die" if no option is passed.

Here is my script but it doesn't seem to "die". Any comments?

```
my $NETLIST;
GetOptions (
    "netlist=s" => \$NETLIST
) or die ("ERROR: Netlist path must be specified.");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) treats its options as, well ... optional.  `GetOptions` is happy if you didn't provide `netlist` on the command line. You need to do a little extra work to check if the option was provided.  Here is one way.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;

my $NETLIST;
GetOptions (
    "netlist=s" => \$NETLIST
) or die ("ERROR: unsupported option.");

die("ERROR: Netlist path must be specified.") unless defined $NETLIST;
```